# Wait for firebase to load until showing View

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I'm currently building an app and i faced some issues. I use Firebase to store the user data and then i display it in some of the views, i managed to create the function to retrieve data with completion, so the async issue is solved, but now when i need to display some of the data it displays nil, because the view is loaded sooner than the firebase loads.

My function to load data from firebase:

```
func getUserFromUID(completion: @escaping (UserData)->()){
    
    
    ref.child("users").child(uid).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]  else { return}
            
            var user = UserData()
            
            if let email = dictionary["email"]{ user.email = email  as? String }
            if let name = dictionary["name"]{ user.name = name  as? String }
            user.firstname = (dictionary["firstname"] as! String)
            user.lastname = (dictionary["lastname"] as! String)
            user.type = (dictionary["type"] as! String)
            user.uid = (dictionary["uid"] as! String)
            user.profileImageUrl = (dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String)
            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.fcmToken2 = (dictionary["fcmToken"] as! String)
            
            
            completion(user)
        }
    }
    
}
```

ChatsHomeView:

```
struct ChatsHomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var session : SessionStore
    @State var user = UserData()
    
    func getUserInfo(){
        session.getUserFromUID { (fetcheduser) in
            self.user = fetcheduser
            print("THE USER:\(user)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Text(user.name ?? "nil")
            Button(action: {
                session.signOut()
            }){ Text("Logout").padding() }
        }.onAppear{
            getUserInfo()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that once the user logins, it displays nil where the ChatsHomeView Text(user.name ?? "nil") field is. I need to restart the app for the field to update and show the Name. Is there a way to show the app launch screen until firebase fully loads, or maybe there is any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS app will certainly be ready to show views before any network operation completes.

The requirement to keep a launch screen visible can be met by having the first VC's UI match the launch view. I've done this in an Objective-C app. In it, that first VC loads the launch view's nib in `viewDidLoad` and sets it as the view.

The completion code for the user snapshot should then check to see if the launch UI is still visible. If it is, it can then change the UI then to one that expects the user data.

**edit** Illustration from an Objective-C project:

In the first VC designated in the main storyboard, grab the UI from your app's launch storyboard and temporarily cover your view with it. The user perception will be that the launch is still happening. Kick off the async work. When it completes, change the UI back...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *storyboardName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UILaunchStoryboardName"];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LaunchVC"];
    UIView *launchView = vc.view;
    
    [self.view addSubview:launchView];
    [self startObserving:^(FIRDocumentSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
          // the async work has completed
          // setup this VC's underlying view with data from the snapshot, then uncover it
          [launchView removeFromSuperview]; 
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Should i just programmatically delay the VC change? Or is there a way for the app to see when all the info is fetched?

Comment: @Pakenas the code block on the observe is executed once the info is fetched.  That's when you'll know you can change the UI.

Comment: I can edit to add my objective-c code, are you able to read the old stuff?  :-)

Comment: Anything will help! Thanks! @danh

Comment: @Pakenas - please see edit. This is from a real objective c project that pulls off the effect of having the launch view stay visible while the initial async work completes.  This is applicable to any async function -- even one that does an async load from a cache on the device.

Answer (score -1):

why not to on firebase offline capability it help you out to auto sync current data and also it will not load to again and again all data

you need to enable `isPersistenceEnabled` property for your firebase database

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

then you need to use `keepSynced(true)` so the data will stay synchronized.

**Persistence Behavior:**

By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored in the cache. Listener callbacks will continue to fire for local updates.

**keepSynced(true):**

The Firebase Realtime Database synchronizes and stores a local copy of the data for active listeners. In addition, you can keep specific locations in sync.

for more info check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

Comment: So if i understand correctly, i need to define that the persistence is true at the top of the function file, or inside the function?

Comment: you can enable it yet after initialize of your database instance

Comment: The problem is, that the data is loading properly once the user logs in and restarts the app, if the user is new and logs in, the values are not displayed until the user restarts the app :/

Comment: no there is no need to restart the app , you can recall fetching function in viewDidAppear, so if user back on screen after new record it will refresh the data

Comment: or if you are inserting data on same screen you can recall fetching function on submit action button success

Comment: solution 3 : or if you are still standing on any screen and want refetch new data you can implement timer to refetch after 5 or 10 sec

Comment: solution 4 : if you have large amount of data you can implement fetch data limit, and can show data through table pagination, means initially you will receive 25 records when you scroll down you will append more 25 records in your data array

Comment: if you find my answers useful you mark this answer correct